# What was the book that you found most useful when learning WSDL?

Tags: web-services, wsdl

I have worked with SOAP in SAAJ and JAXM, and I want to extend on that, and throw in some WSDL and UDDI.

What was, for you, the most useful book or article when you learned WSDL? What tools came in handy when trying to create and run some examples?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering my own question since I did not get a lot of responses.

I eventually found a good article and used it as a basis for beginning to learn WSDL. I extended on it by reading other articles similar to the one specified by adatapost or by google-ing. For specific details I turned to the specifications as John Saunders suggested.

This is the material that I found most useful when starting to learn WSDL: [Understanding WSDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996486.aspx). Hope it helps somebody else too.

Answer (score 0):

[Web Services Description Language (WSDL) 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl)

but also

[WS-I Basic Profile Version 1.1](http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.1.html) to learn what parts of WSDL to not use.

Comment: Using the W3C specs as learning material won't get you very far... they're specs, not tutorials.